# Not able to install REALMD on RedHat 6.8 VM

Tags: linux, bash, redhat, rhel, rhel6

I am not able to install REALMD on Red Hat 6.8 VM hosted in Azure. I have even configured EPEL repositories using this [link](http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-enable-epel-repository-for-rhel-centos-6-5/). Without this package we are not able to join the linux VM to our domain as described in this [Official Link on RedHat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Windows_Integration_Guide/realmd-domain.html) or [this link on Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-ds-admin-guide-join-rhel-linux-vm/#join-the-linux-virtual-machine-to-the-managed-domain) (where our VM is located).

I have internet connectivity on the VM and I am able to install other packages.

Any Pointers as to where to look or what to check.

**Screenshot**:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`realmd` is not supported in RHEL 6, you should upgrade to RHEL 7 in order to use it. I've seen this confirmed at https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2273711, although I think it requires logging in to Red Hat customer portal.

Comment: Thanks @Mureinik. Once I knew this I tried manual configurations. I was able to connect the VM to ad using this blog: https://fedorahosted.org/sssd/wiki/Configuring_sssd_with_ad_server